# Searching for a Library of Simulink models of Fuel cells

Tags: modeling, simulation, simulink

I have a task at hand and in order to do that I must create a model library of Simulink/Simscape (or any other similar software) of models.

Can I find such models in excess anywhere? The models must vary in their purpose (like efficiency study) and complexity (first oder modeling, second order modelling)

Please let me know if there is any such source.

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: How do you think a fuel cell works? What makes for the state(s) of a fuel cell? Follow the energy!

Comment: @jsotola No this is not an assignment. I am working on a project and if I can find a library like this, then I can do work quicker because this acts as input. Anywho, if anybody knows any, please let me know.